# area between two curves 10

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the following curves:

$$y=7\cos(2x) ,\quad y=7-7\cos(2x) ,\quad [0,\pi/2].$$

I found the boundaries (calculations not shown but they are correct)

$7\cos(2x) > 7-7\cos(2x), \quad[0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$

$7-7\cos(2x) > 7\cos(2x),\quad [\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}]$
\begin{align*}
&\int 7 \cos(2x) - 7-7\cos(2x)~dx\\
=& \frac{7}{2}\sin(2x)-7x-\frac{7}{2} \sin(2x).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\left[{\frac{7}{2}\sin(2x)-7x-\frac{7}{2} \sin(2x)}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\\
=& -\frac{7\pi}{2} - 0 =-\frac{7\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\left[7x-\frac{7}{2} \sin(2x)- \frac{7}{2}\sin(2x)\right]_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}}\\
=& \frac{35\pi}{6}+\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{7\pi}{6}-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\left[{\frac{7}{2}\sin(2x)-7x-\frac{7}{2} \sin(2x)}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}+\left[7x-\frac{7}{2} \sin(2x)- \frac{7}{2}\sin(2x)\right]_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}}\\
=&-\frac{7\pi}{2} + \frac{35\pi}{6}+\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{7\pi}{6}-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
=& \frac{7\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

This answer was wrong. I double checked my work and have no clue why its not right. To me it seems correct. Can anyone verify?

Comment: How does finding the area between $2$ curves from $0$ to $\pi/2$ involve an integral out to $5\pi/6$?

Comment: Ah ah ah, I see. You are absolutely correct. the intervals should be $[0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$ and $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ nice catch!

Comment: Yes, that'll make a difference all right :)

Comment: Thank you! I will start again and let you know :)

Comment: I am still coming back to the same answer. I have double and triple checked using those intervals.

Comment: I get $15.78955$....what do you get?

Comment: I am still getting $\frac{7\pi}{2}$

Comment: I understand if you don't want to take the time to show the calculations. But what did you get as a fraction? maybe I can see if I can obtain that answer.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Check your signs:

$$\int 7 \cos(2x) - \Big(7 - 7\cos(2x) \Big)$$
$$= \int 7 \cos(2x) - 7 \color{red}{+} 7\cos(2x)$$
$$= \frac{7}{2} \cos(2x) - 7x \color{red}{+} \frac{7}{2} \sin(2x)$$

Comment: **sigh** yep, missed that one. Thank you

Comment: @user583753 No problem!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{\pi/6} 14 \cos(2x) - 7\ dx +\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} 7 - 14 \cos(2x)\ dx$$

$$[7\sin(2x) - 7x]_0^{\pi/6} + [7x - 7\sin(2x)]_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}$$

$$[7\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})-\frac{7\pi}{6}]+[\frac{7\pi}{2}-7\sin(\pi)-\frac{7\pi}{6}+7\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})]$$

$$[7\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})-\frac{7\pi}{6}]+[\frac{7\pi}{3}+7\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})]$$

$$ = 2.396986 + 13.392561 = 15.78955$$